# The method 'fromMap' isn't defined for the type 'GroupBy'

Tags: flutter

I am struggling to find a solution to my problem.
the error that appears is

The method 'fromMap' isn't defined for the type 'GroupBy'.

my model

```
import 'dart:convert';

class GroupBy {
  GroupBy({
    this.id,
    this.date,
    this.selectdate,
    this.descript,
    this.title,
    this.idEventDate,
  });

  final int? id;
  final DateTime? date;
  final DateTime? selectdate;
  final String? descript;
  final String? title;
  final int? idEventDate;

  factory GroupBy.fromRawJson(String str) => GroupBy.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory GroupBy.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GroupBy(
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        date: json["date"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["date"]),
        selectdate: json["selectdate"] == null
            ? null
            : DateTime.parse(json["selectdate"]),
        descript: json["descript"] == null ? null : json["descript"],
        title: json["title"] == null ? null : json["title"],
        idEventDate:
            json["id_event_date"] == null ? null : json["id_event_date"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id == null ? null : id,
        "date": date == null
            ? null
            : "${date!.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${date!.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${date!.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "selectdate": selectdate == null
            ? null
            : "${selectdate!.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${selectdate!.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${selectdate!.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "descript": descript == null ? null : descript,
        "title": title == null ? null : title,
        "id_event_date": idEventDate == null ? null : idEventDate,
      };
}
```

here is the code that i have been trying to run since without success. can you help me ?

```
loadPreviousEvents() async {
    var url = 'http://xxxxxxx/getEvents.php';
    var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var response = res.body as List;
    print(response);
    (response.map((e) async => await GroupBy.fromMap(e))).toList();
  }
```

Comment: You need to replace `fromMap` with `fromJson`

Comment: i have this error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast here var response = res.body as List;

Comment: Hey, @ZanaSouleymaneCoulibaly will you able to share the JSON response or a gist of the JSON response, I think you're JSON isn't proper, and yeah somewhat your code is also not proper. So, maybe I will be able to provide you with a solution to your problem based on your JSON response.

Comment: print(res.body); ------>>>>>>[{"date":"2022-09-17","eventDescp":"azerty","eventTitle":"azertyui"},{"date":"2022-09-17","eventDescp":"11","eventTitle":"AZE"},{"date":"2022-09-17","eventDescp":"22","eventTitle":"4556"},{"date":"2022-09-20","eventDescp":"77","eventTitle":"HHJ"},{"date":"2022-09-17","eventDescp":"44","eventTitle":"BYYY"}]

Answer (score 0):

the `response.body` isn't decoded yet, so it's just a `String`, so you're trying to call a `List` method which is `map` over a String.

from what I see, you have a method that it's decode the `JSON` string, which is
the fromJson, so try this :

```
loadPreviousEvents() async {
var url = 'http://xxxxxxx/getEvents.php';
var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
var response = res.body as String;
print(response);
(response.map((e) async => await GroupBy.fromJson(e))).toList();
}
```

Comment: i have this error  type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast here var response = res.body as List;

Comment: sorry, I edited it now, the response body is String a I say

Comment: The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'map'.

Answer (score 0):

change your **fromMap** to **fromJson**

Before:

```
  loadPreviousEvents() async {
  var url = 'http://xxxxxxx/getEvents.php';
  var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  var response = res.body as List;
  print(response);
  (response.map((e) async => await 
  GroupBy.fromMap(e))).toList();
  }
```

After:

```
  loadPreviousEvents() async {
  var url = 'http://xxxxxxx/getEvents.php';
  var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  var response = res.body as List;
  print(response);
  (response.map((e) async => await 
  GroupBy.fromJson(e))).toList();
  }
```

Comment: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast